# Select2entity not working with embed forms

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have this code

```
->add('product', Select2EntityType::class, [
            'remote_route'          => 'search',
            'class'                 => Product::class,
            'primary_key'           => 'id',
            'text_property'         => 'name',
            'minimum_input_length'  => 2,
            'page_limit'            => 10,
            'allow_clear'           => true,
            'delay'                 => 250,
            'cache'                 => true,
            'cache_timeout'         => 60000, // if 'cache' is true
            'language'              => 'fr',
            'placeholder'           => 'yep',
            'allow_add'             => [
                'enabled'               => true,
                'new_tag_text'          => '',
                'tag_separators'        => '[".", ","]'
            ],
            'multiple'             => false,
            'attr'                 => [
                'style' => 'width:100%'
            ],
            'scroll'               => true,
        ])
```

My html :

```
{% block main %}
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
       <div id="dynamic-relations-elements" class="hidden">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_javascript %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/js/users.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/tetranzselect2entity/js/select2entity.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock body_javascript %}
```

In `ventilation.js` I have :

```
$('#dynamic-relations-elements').removeClass('hidden');
  $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: Routing.generate('create'),
     success: function (response) {
        $('#dynamic-relations-elements').html(response);
     }
})
```

And the route for building form :

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajax/product-create", name="create",
 *     options      = { "expose" = true })
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function createProduct()
{
    $productVen = new Product();

    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $productVen);

    return $this->render('/users/add-product.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

The problem is that the selectbox is not initalized. I have for field `product` a simple text input and not an selectbox. I have no errors in browser console. Any ideas please ? Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/tetranz/select2entity-bundle/blob/master/Resources/public/js/select2entity.js) lines 144 - 148 you will see how the elements are initialized:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.select2entity[data-autostart="true"]').select2entity();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

In your case this initially happens before the form exists. So it looks like you just need to manually initialize the element.
Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: Routing.generate('_route_ventilation_products_create'),
     success: function (response) {
         let $dre = $('#dynamic-relations-elements');
         $dre.html(response);
         let $s2 = $dre.find('.select2entity');
         $s2.select2entity();
         $s2.on('change', function(){
           // do something with selected value
           console.log(this.id, $(this).find(':selected').val());
         });
     }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @Arleigh Hix, now the select is initiallised but without config that I put in form : so no correct placeholder but the default one, and no products appear in the select, is just a empty select

Comment: @klsdskldsd did you configure the form theme in config/packages/twig.yaml?

Comment: one more thing please : is possible to listen in jquery for select value from select2entity. For example get the selected value in jquery from select2entity

Comment: @klsdskldsd yes see my edit,  it works with standard `<select>`, I didn't test with Select2EntityType